# Split string into words in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am looking to split a string into words in columns in SQL Server 2014. I have found a few solutions but all of them are giving the results in rows. How can I break the below string into columns?

> "First Second Third Fourth Fifth"

Comment: Dear Jessica. For your future questions, please bear in mind that the members of this community are here volunteering on their free time helping fellow developers. We don't and shouldn't care if a problem is urgent for the person that asked the question. Besides, if you want to get good help and fast, ask good questions. You can start by reading [ask], and specifically for SQL related questions, read the excellent post over on meta.dba.stackexchange called [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). Thank you for reading

Comment: Feedback: several times in your post history, people have asked to see your initial attempt, or have asked for a clarification, and these generally are not forthcoming. Please get into the habit of making changes to your questions when asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [SQL split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) to seperate the string into words and using the order of the word in the original string, you can use CASE statements like a PIVOT query and display as columns

Here is a sample

```
declare @string varchar(max) = 'First Second Third Fourth Fifth'

;with cte as (
select
    case when id = 1 then val end as Col1,
    case when id = 2 then val end as Col2,
    case when id = 3 then val end as Col3,
    case when id = 4 then val end as Col4,
    case when id = 5 then val end as Col5
from dbo.split( @string,' ')
)
select
    max(Col1) as Col1,
    max(Col2) as Col2,
    max(Col3) as Col3,
    max(Col4) as Col4,
    max(Col5) as Col5
from cte
```

If you cannot create a UDF, you can use the logic in your SQL code as follows

Please note that if you have your data in a database table column, you can simply replace column content in the first [SQL CTE expression](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18)

```
declare @string varchar(max) = 'First Second Third Fourth Fifth'

;with cte1 as (
    select convert(xml, N'<root><r>' + replace(@string,' ','</r><r>') + '</r></root>') as rawdata
), cte2 as (
  select
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by getdate()) as id,
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as val
  from cte1
  cross apply rawdata.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)
)
select
    max(Col1) as Col1,
    max(Col2) as Col2,
    max(Col3) as Col3,
    max(Col4) as Col4,
    max(Col5) as Col5
from (
    select
        case when id = 1 then val end as Col1,
        case when id = 2 then val end as Col2,
        case when id = 3 then val end as Col3,
        case when id = 4 then val end as Col4,
        case when id = 5 then val end as Col5
    from cte2
) t
```

Comment: Hi Eralper, thank you for your kind reply. I dont have rights to create a function in DB. Can you modify the query please?

Comment: I added a second query Jessica

Comment: Hi Eralper, your updated query would work, but just to mention this: If the string contains forbidden characters (like `&`) this will break. This might pass all internal tests and break in production... Furthermore it seems to be reliable, but there is no documentation about `ROW_NUMBER`, which would guarantee, that the elements are returned in the expected order... You might have a look at the last example in my answer for a *position-safe* inline splitter.

Comment: Thank you Shnugo, the trick for eliminating & similar characters using "   SELECT @string AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')  " is very interesting!

Answer (score 2):

You can use XML and grab the elements by their position:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='First Second Third Fourth Fifth';

WITH StringAsXML AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @YourString AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) TheXml
)
SELECT TheXml.value('x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FirstElement
      ,TheXml.value('x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SecondElement
      ,TheXml.value('x[3]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ThirdElement
      ,TheXml.value('x[4]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FourthElement
      ,TheXml.value('x[5]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FifthElement
FROM StringAsXML;
```

### Remark

You can use `PIVOT`, *conditional aggregation*, `FROM(VALUES())` or the above. but any of these approaches will need a known set of columns (a known count of elements or at least a maximum count of elements).

If you cannot rely on such a knowledge, you can use *dynamically created SQL*. This would mean to create one of the working statements on string base and use `EXEC` for a dynamic execution.

### UPDATE: A dynamic approach

This approach will deal with a variable number of elements

```sql
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='First Second Third Fourth Fifth';
DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR(1)=' ';
DECLARE @countElements INT = LEN(@YourString)-LEN(REPLACE(@YourString,@Delimiter,''));

DECLARE @Statement VARCHAR(MAX)=
'WITH StringAsXML AS
(
    SELECT CAST(''<x>'' + REPLACE((SELECT ''ReplaceYourString'' AS [*] FOR XML PATH('''')),'' '',''</x><x>'') + ''</x>'' AS XML) TheXml
)
SELECT ReplaceColumnList
FROM StringAsXML;';

DECLARE @columnList VARCHAR(MAX);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ElementCounter
          ,CAST('TheXml.value(''x[1]/text()[1]'',''nvarchar(max)'') AS Element_01' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColStatement
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT cte.ElementCounter+1
          ,cte.ColStatement + CAST(',TheXml.value(''x[' + CAST(cte.ElementCounter+1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']/text()[1]'',''nvarchar(max)'') AS Element_' + REPLACE(STR(cte.ElementCounter + 1,2),' ','0') AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM cte
    WHERE cte.ElementCounter <= @countElements
)
SELECT @columnList=(SELECT TOP 1 cte.ColStatement FROM cte ORDER BY cte.ElementCounter DESC)

--replace the string you want to split
SET @Statement = REPLACE(@Statement,'ReplaceYourString',@YourString);
--replace the columnList
SET @Statement = REPLACE(@Statement,'ReplaceColumnList',@columnList);

EXEC(@Statement);
```

### UPDATE 2: The smallest fully inlined and *position-safe* splitter I know of

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @inp VARCHAR(200) = 'First Second Third Fourth Fifth';
DECLARE @dlmt VARCHAR(100)=' ';

;WITH
a AS (SELECT n=0, i=-1, j=0 UNION ALL SELECT n+1, j, CHARINDEX(@dlmt, @inp, j+1) FROM a WHERE j > i),
b AS (SELECT n, SUBSTRING(@inp, i+1, IIF(j>0, j, LEN(@inp)+1)-i-1) s FROM a WHERE i >= 0)
SELECT * FROM b;
```

And just to get it complete: The above tiny splitter combined with `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH
a AS (SELECT n=0, i=-1, j=0 UNION ALL SELECT n+1, j, CHARINDEX(@dlmt, @inp, j+1) FROM a WHERE j > i),
b AS (SELECT n, SUBSTRING(@inp, i+1, IIF(j>0, j, LEN(@inp)+1)-i-1) s FROM a WHERE i >= 0)

SELECT p.* 
FROM b
PIVOT(MAX(s) FOR n IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `parsename` function as :

```
create table tab ( str varchar(100));

insert into tab values('First Second Third Fourth Fifth');

with t as
(
select replace(str,' ','.') as str
  from tab
)    
Select substring(str,1,charindex('.',str)-1) as col_first,
       parsename(substring(str,charindex('.',str)+1,len(str)),4) as col_second,
       parsename(substring(str,charindex('.',str)+1,len(str)),3) as col_third,
       parsename(substring(str,charindex('.',str)+1,len(str)),2) as col_fourth,
       parsename(substring(str,charindex('.',str)+1,len(str)),1) as col_fifth
  from t;

col_first   col_second  col_third   col_fourth  col_fifth
---------   ----------  ---------   ----------  ---------
First       Second      Third       Fourth      Fifth
```

*P.S. firstly, need to split the main string into the parts with at most 3 three dot(`.`) character(otherwise the function doesn't work). It's a restriction for `parsename`.*

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/NGAQM59606)

Comment: The given example shows clearly, that there are more than four parts. `PARSENAME` is - for sure! - the wrong choice here... (in my eyes it is the wrong choice for string splitting in almost any case...)

Comment: @Shnugo for that reason I've splitted the string into two parts each containing three dots at most.

Comment: @Shnugo It's OK with splitting once.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with *splitting once*... For me it's the wrong tool, because it is to specific and completely non-intuitive with the reverse numbering.